# socket.ip expressjs listen is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

trying some project related to websockets, below code output an error

> TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function

below is my attempt

```
const app = require("express")();
const port = 3800;
const io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
```

and the line of code that was pointed is

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
```

any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require('socket.io')` returns the socket.io module and it does not have the `.listen()` method directly on it.  That's why you get the error message you do.  There are a dozen ways to initialize socket.io.  In this case, you can do this:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(app.listen(port));
```

If you want to use socket.io's `.listen`, you have to get the Server class from socket.io first because that's where the method is.